# Dimensions and parts of Fort Douglas, Winnipeg Canada

Tags: 18th-century, battle, canada

I am having troubles estimating the dimensions of Fort Douglas that WAS in Winnipeg Canada. Fort Douglas (from what I understand, correct me if I'm wrong) was the stage of the battle of Seven Oaks. I can't seem to find much since the original building was washed away in a flood, but I was able to find this picture:  
[image]
However this picture does not show the rest of the fort.So, my main Questions:

#### Dimensions

- The width and length (the height of the walls would be awesome, but not neccesary)
- Approximate will do just as well, although I am trying to be as accurate as possible.

#### Things inside the fort

- All the buildings inside.
- Can be approximate.
- An image, whether drawn by yourself, or by someone else would be the best, laying out the locations and titles of the different building inside the fort.

HOWEVER! if you cannot find information about this fort you can provide information about the dimension and buildings inside a Canadian fort of a similar time period.

Comment: Forts were of all different sizes and configurations, so there is nothing that would be "typical". Also, they would evolve constantly. A building being there one year, and gone the next. Fort Douglas was very small compared to the other forts in Winnipeg, such as Fort Garry.

Comment: That picture above, dated 1817, clearly show the rough outlines of the fort: two corner towers about 200 or so feet apart anchoring a wooden palisade and enclosing a handful of modest buildings.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens So, like this: http://www.vrdwellers.net/hcorion/images/map.png So the side length would be about 141.42 Ft? I used Cosine to figure that one out btw.

Comment: Two towers, diagonally opposite corners, and a bit more rectangular; almost twice as long as wide it appears to me..

Comment: Square would have maximized area to perimeter, so I expect the off-square is to take advantage of the available level ground. At a minimum buildings would have included a barracks, officer's quarters, locked Quartermaster's office (supplies), and a partitioned Mess Hall.